# load NOAA ENC s-57 chart?

Tags: import

Is it possible to load a NOAA ENC s-57 formatted nautical chart into MMA 9.x?

- Particularly in MMA9.x within the MAC OS?

-There does not appear to be any discussion of importing nautical charts into Mathematica in a manner that preserves the Mercator latitude projection along with all the nautical data.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this format?

Comment: In the interim period you can use the [NOAA ENC Direct to GIS](http://encdirect.noaa.gov/ENC_Direct/encdirect_download.html) download tool to download this information in GIS formats known to Mathematica.

Comment: Reference to S-57 format: http://www.gdal.org/drv_s57.html